# Linux freezes completely including mouse, keyboard

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I recently downloaded Ubuntu Linux on my laptop as dual boot. Linux was freezing everytime after login ( it can work for a max of 3 mins before freezing). It completely freezes including keyboard, mouse and only solution is to force the computer to shut down. The problem resolved itself on its own. Unfortunately because I allocated too little disk space for Linux I had to uninstall and reinstall it. It is now freezing again and I'm in a hurry I need to work on it today! Is there anything I could do?
I tried doing system update but I cannot reach that point before the computer freezes.
Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe is something related to this issue: [Ubuntu freezes minutes after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275360/ubuntu-20-04-freezes-minutes-after-login). You could try boot from another kernel (but since is a clean installation I suppose you will have only one kernel, if so, you could try installing another kernel vesison if it's possible)

Comment: Or instead of login in the desktop environment you could try login only with command line using a virtual console pressing Ctrl alt fn, where fn is function key from F1 to F7 or F12 (the maximum virtual value for Fn depends on the configuration of the operating system)